# Creating search bar to filter array into table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I'm trying to use a search bar to filter values into a table. So if any of the values in the array matches the value in search bar then display them into table.

I want it so:

- If you searched "A" you'd get all the values in Array when match "A". E.g. (Only show object if the First name and last name included "A"; **Show name:** Adam, **Don't show name:** Eden)
- If you searched "AD (consecutive)" you'd get all the values in Array which include "A" and "D". E.g. (Only show object if the First name and last name included "A" and "D"; **Show name:** Adam, **Don't show name:** Eden)

However every time I do the live search, I'm experiencing that the values duplicate in the table. So If I had "Adam", I would search "A" then search "AD", he would should twice in the table.

**Current code:**

```
// Stored Patient List
var storedPatientList = new Array();

// Variables for limiting Patients on show
var patientsToShow = 15;

// On page select initialize functions
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // Get latest patient list
    GetPatientListData();

    $("#patientListSearch").on("keyup keypress", function() 
    {
        FilterPatientListBasedOnLiveSearch($("#patientListSearch").val());
    });
});

// Get all patient information for patient list, and append to patient list table (Patient List page)
function GetPatientListData()
{

    $.post("php/getPatientList.php",
    {
        command: "getAllPatientsList"
    })

    .success(function (data)
    {
        // Store patient list so you don't have to keep on reloading list
        storedPatientList = JSON.parse(data); 
        $(".patientListHiddenNotice").css("display", "none");
    });
}

function FilterPatientListBasedOnLiveSearch(filter) 
{

    // Create a new array to store the Patients at multiple points
    var originalPatientList = new Array();
    var newPatientList = new Array();
    var tableRecord = '';

    originalPatientList = storedPatientList;

    if (filter)
    {
        if (originalPatientList.RESPONSE == "OK")
        {

            // If so, loop through the old Patient list
            for(var i = 0; i < originalPatientList.RECORDS.length; i++)
            {
                var currentRecord = originalPatientList.RECORDS[i];
                // Check if the filter matches the Patient being checked
                if((currentRecord["patientFirstname"] + " " + currentRecord["patientSurname"]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                {
                    // If so, push the Patient into the new list
                    trustArray.push("<tr id=" + currentRecord["PatientID"] + "><td class='patientListNames'>" + currentRecord["patientFirstname"] + " " + currentRecord["patientSurname"] + "</td><td>" + currentRecord["patientNHSID"] + "</td></tr>");                
                }
            }
            tableRecord = trustArray;
        }
    }

    $('#dataTables-example').find('tbody').html(tableRecord);
}
```

**What the objects look like:**

```
Object {PatientID: "1438684398979xWug5A6Y", Registered: "1438684398982", patientType: "mother", patientFirstname: "Georgina", patientSurname: "Whitaker"…}
Object {PatientID: "1438684464931cv4wTysi", Registered: "1438684464932", patientType: "baby", patientFirstname: "Baby Boy", patientSurname: "Whitaker"…}
Object {PatientID: "1438684572193rttTQY4N", Registered: "1438684572194", patientType: "mother", patientFirstname: "June", patientSurname: "Rayfield"…}
Object {PatientID: "14386846626984c1HzsCa", Registered: "1438684662699", patientType: "baby", patientFirstname: "Eva", patientSurname: "Rayfield"…}
Object {PatientID: "1438684871330rM0qgjJf", Registered: "1438684871332", patientType: "mother", patientFirstname: "Fiona", patientSurname: "Smith"…}
```

**JS Fiddle Example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/kng44rp9/1/

Could somebody look at my current code and try and point me in the right direction of what to do?

Comment: If you want individual character matching need nested loop to test for characters not the whole `filter` value

Comment: @charlietfl could you give an example of this?

Comment: loop over `filter.split('')` for example

Comment: @charlietfl I don't see why I need to use `.split('')`

Comment: Am i understanding correctly you want any character to be a match? If so that would give you array of characters. Not sure why a filter mechanism would work this way though ... not intuitive

Comment: @charlietfl I've updated the question to give you an idea

Comment: ok, if you only want last name to match filter, why are you concatenating first name into the string to test then?

Comment: Have you tried using jquery datatables (https://www.datatables.net/)? It has global search and column specific search built-in.

Comment: Provide a demo with enough data that explains the issue more clearly. Your approach should work fine to match consecutive characters and if you want to only check last name then don't look at first name too. Filter criteria expected is not totally clear

Comment: @charlietfl I've updated my question with JSFiddle example, and Surname was just an example

Comment: @jumojer I don't want to use datatables

Comment: @charlietfl Could it be because i'm not emptying the array everytime i'm searching?

Comment: yes...that is defintiely a problem and array should be only stored within the function ... try this https://jsfiddle.net/kng44rp9/2/  Note that you never mentioned the duplicates in your problem description

Comment: Instead of starting question with `how to do`...start with problems or unexpected behaviors you have, then explain expected behavior. Would have gotten to the bottom of this much sooner

Comment: @charlietfl Cheers, would you like to post your jsfiddle as a answer to my question? and I'm sorry about not state the problems and unexpected behaviors; your tips have been taken in.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett when you say: *`if the First name and last name included "A" and "D"`* you mean actually "AD" (consecutive) as in "**Ad**am" ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating the array outside of the function, whenever you push to it while doing a new filter the old entries are still in the array.

Here's a simpler solution using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that creates a new array each time a search is made

```
function FilterPatientListBasedOnLiveSearch(filterVal) {

    // Create a new array to store the Patients at multiple points

    filterVal = filterVal.toLowerCase();
    var trustArray = PatientList.map(function (patient) {
        // return patient if search is empty or last name matches
        if (!filterVal || patient.patientSurname.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterVal) !== -1) {
            return "<tr id=" + patient.PatientID + "><td class='patientListNames'>" + patient.patientFirstname + " " + patient.patientSurname + "</td></tr>"
        }

    });

    $('#dataTables-example').find('tbody').html(trustArray);
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kng44rp9/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Cheers for this. Thank you for helping out

Comment: I don't get it... if I type "D" as the search query... why all users appear? also why if I start typing "J" there's no "jake" patient as result? Am I missing something terribly obvious?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan In charlietfl example, he only shows it filtering by Surname

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan only filtering last name, criteria is still unclear and was changed around ... all patients have `d` in last name